# unwind segue result different with master and detail views

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, popover, unwind-segue

i'm fairly new to swift and having some difficulty with unwind segues in a master detail application.

the unwind seems to work fine dismissing my popovers on the iPhone, however when i try the same thing on the iPad, the popover remains.

If i add a dismissViewControllerAnimated to the presenting viewController's unwind handling action, then the iPad version works fine and dismisses the popover, however the iPhone version dismisses the popover and then dismisses the view that presented the popover.  i.e. dismisses two views.

I have worked out that the problem is that popover's are automatically dismissed with an unwind when presented modally such as on an iPhone.  However when presented as true popovers they don't dismiss with an unwind segue.  Could somebody help me figure out how to manage both cases so that only the popover will be dismissed.  Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  after a long time working on this i managed to come up with a solution.  i used a popoverpresentationcontroller and declared the presenting controller as the delegate.  by then adding an additional function forcing the iPhone to use the popover in lieu of the modal presentation, the presentation and dismissal is consistent for the iPhone and iPad.  the code is below.  I just used a generic UIViewController in the if let vc statement so that I could use this with a popover that's imbedded in a navigation controller also.

> ```
> override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
>     if let identifier = segue.identifier {
>         switch identifier {
>         case "My Segue Identifier" :
>             if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? UIViewController {
>                 if let ppc = vc.popoverPresentationController {
>                     ppc.delegate = self
>                 }
>             }
>         default: break
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

additionally you need to add the following function to prevent the modal presentation on the iPhone:

> ```
> func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController (controller:UIPresentationController)-> UIModalPresentationStyle {
>     return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
> }
> ```

Comment: also don't forget to conform to the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate in the presenting controller